# Apache ibatis postgresql selectList how it it works

Tags: java, postgresql, ibatis

I have installed postgresql enterprise DB and created some tables

In one of the example. I see the following code.

```
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
.....
SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession();
.....
List list =  session.selectList("findAllData-Data", params);
```

What it does? **findAllData-Data** means what? I have only created tables in postgresql, but I don't see the table name in above code

Comment: ibatis is retired, if you want to create a new project, you can use [mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/) instead. `findAllData-Data` in your example is a [pre-configured](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check up the documentation for [selectList](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSession.html#selectList(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object))

`"findAllData-Data"` is the unique identifier matching the statement to use. Statements are usually defined in some mapper .xml file or in newer versions in annotation of a class, so grep your code for `findAllData-Data` in order to find the definition.